# how does tuned store the active profile to be run

Tags: tuned

in RHEL 7.9 specifically if it matters, doing

```
systemctl enable tuned --now

tuned-adm profile hpc-compute
```

the default profile is `throughput-performance`.

I have a virtual filesystem, that I `chroot` to which is used to boot diskless nodes of a cluster system.  Enabling the tuned service works however starting the service with either the `--now` or doing `service tuned start` within the chrooted file system fails, which makes sense.  But the only way I know how to change the profile  is via the command above, which also fails stating the tuned service is not running.  A chicken-egg sort of problem.

I don't want to have my diskless compute nodes boot and then every time have to ssh in and do `tuned-adm profile hpc-compute` to change the profile.

Where, as in is there a file, that the `tuned-adm profile` command changes, that I can go manually edit, where it says *defaultprofile = X* ?  That way I can modify my virtual filesystem so that tuned kicks off with the profile I want.

for clarification - the warning I do get from `tuned-adm profile <whatever>` under the chroot'ed file system does not mean it didn't set it to a new profile.  It does work.  But per my original question, I still would like to know if tuned modifies some .conf file or something somethere where it states in plain text what the profile will be when the service starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a directory called /etc/tuned   Within that are sub directories that match the available profiles.  There is several other files in /etc/tuned for fine tuning,  but there should be a /etc/tuned/active_profile that will have the current profile.